# SQL Count similar records

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, group-by, case

Let's say I have not user-friendly table called Animals.
Like so:

```
ID NAME CHANGED
1  Dog  2016-01-02
2  Dog  2016-01-05
3  Dog2 2016-01-05
4  Dog3 2016-01-06
5  Cat  2016-01-06
6  Fish 2016-01-07
7  Cat2 2016-01-07
```

And I want to count how many similar words are in the table that begins the same way but could end different. Also I would only want to show just Names without additional '2' or '3'. To be more precise I want such result:

```
Counted NAME
4       Dog
2       Cat
1       Fish
```

And here is the code I've been trying to get along with ( have tried many ways ):

```
SELECT COUNT(
CASE
    WHEN NAME LIKE '%' + NAME + '%' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
END
) AS Counted, NAME FROM Animals
WHERE NAME LIKE '%' + NAME + '%' AND
    NAME NOT LIKE '%2' AND
    NAME NOT LIKE '%3'
    GROUP BY NAME
    ORDER BY Counted DESC
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO

Comment: You have to define the animals category in separate table this will never work out

Comment: Do you just want to strip numbers?  Or do you also want to match values like `dog` and `dogg` and `doggy`?

Comment: @iamdave It could be either way. But in this case let it be just numbers.

Comment: @prdp No you don't. There is a way ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tedious but simple method is to strip your data off numeric characters:

```
select new_name,
       count(*) as counted
from   (
       select replace(replace(replace....replace(Name, '0', ''), '1', ''), '2','')... as new_name
       from   Animals
       ) as a
group by new_name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select case when patIndex('%[0-9]', val) = 0 then val  
    else substring(val, 1, patIndex('%[0-9]', val)-1) end,  count(*)
from table
Group by case when patIndex('%[0-9]', val) = 0 then val  
    else substring(val, 1, patIndex('%[0-9]', val)-1) end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the animals category in separate table this will never work out. Grouping will be very difficult with different spelling for same animal.

If it is always numbers at the end of animals name then

```
select left(Name,isnull(nullif(patindex('%[0-9]%',Name)-1,-1),len(Name))),count(1)
From yourtable 
Group by left(Name,isnull(nullif(patindex('%[0-9]%',Name)-1,-1),len(Name)))
```

Comment: @Prdp Ok but lets say there are not numbers: 'dog', 'dogg' 'doggee' How would you do it then? Without creating #temp tables ? ..

Comment: @user240179  You can't.  That is incredibly complex data manipulation.

Comment: @user240179 - I will write dog as dag now how will you categorize ? As I as said earlier have a separate table for animals list and refer the `ID` in your current table life will be so much easier

Comment: @Prdp it has only to do with beginning as I mentioned. Dag and Dog 2 different things. It has to start the same but ending could be different

Answer (score 0):

This will remove all numbers from your data, regardless of how many there are or where they are in your data.  It is a bit ridiculous, but then sometimes SQL just is...

```
declare @t table(ID int, Name nvarchar(10), Changed date);
insert into @t values
 (1  ,'Dog','20160102')
,(2  ,'Dog','20160105')
,(3  ,'Dog2','20160105')
,(4  ,'Dog30','20160106')
,(5  ,'Cat','20160106')
,(6  ,'Fish','20160107')
,(7  ,'Cat27676','20160107');

select count(1) as Counted
        ,replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(Name
            , '0', ''),'1', ''),'2', ''),'3', ''),'4', ''),'5', ''),'6', ''),'7', ''),'8', ''),'9', '') as Name
from @t
group by replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(Name
            , '0', ''),'1', ''),'2', ''),'3', ''),'4', ''),'5', ''),'6', ''),'7', ''),'8', ''),'9', '')
order by Counted desc;
```

Output:

```
+---------+------+
| Counted | Name |
+---------+------+
|       4 | Dog  |
|       2 | Cat  |
|       1 | Fish |
+---------+------+
```